# how to host silverlight project local

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

i want to debug my program but i can't host my silverlight project in VS 2010
here is the message that the VS send to me:

"the Silverlight project you are about to debug uses web service. Call to the web service will fail unless the Silverlight is host and launched from the same web project contains the web service"

when I search about it in the web i saw that the problem is that I'm not doing it local
so when I tried to change this line

```
endpoint address="http://xxx.xx.x.x/WebService/Service1.svc"
```

to

```
endpoint address="http://localhost/WebService/Service1.svc"
```

on this file:
ServiceReferences.ClientConfig

**update!!**

i tried now to do it like this:

```
endpoint address="http://localhost:54502/Service1.svc"
```

and i got and error that says:

```
the remote server returned an error:NotFound
```

here:

```
 public int EndAddParticipant(System.IAsyncResult result) {
                object[] _args = new object[0];
                int _result = ((int)(base.EndInvoke("AddParticipant", _args, result)));
                return _result;
```

what should i do to change it?
i saw that i need to turn on the debug in web.config file but it was already on.

Comment: Add a new empty web project to your solution, then in prpject settings add your silverlight project as a silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain well so here are a bunch of answers:

When you created your solution, you should have told it to host in a web site.

You can do this after the fact but it is a lot of work (for a new guy), you're better off starting over and copying your code from your silverlight project.

If you did but you are trying to connect to another web site as your web service, you will have to implement a Cross Domain configuration file. This opens a big security hole though.

If you have the 2 projects, but your issue is just the "ServiceReferences.ClientConfig" file not pointing the the right server, you need to include the PORT when debugging locally.  It should look something like this:

```
http://localhost:12345/Service1.svc
```

Where 12345 is the port of your local web service. You can find this out by looking at the "Web" tab of your project properties.

Hope one of these does it. If not, please provide a little more info, like all the important stuff behind the phrase, "it didn't work"!

Comment: One, this is another issue altogether. Two, this usually means you did connect to it now but there was an error. You'll find consuming web service in Silverlight suck because "Not Found" is the error you get for everything.  You will need to use fidler or something to try to find out what the real error is. [Debugging Not Found](https://www.google.com/#q=debugging+silverlight+not+found+error)